# Official 7inch touchscreen dead zone

Tags: touchscreen

I have a 7 inch touchscreen which has been working fine over the last few years but recently it has a dead zone across the centre (full width, landscape orientation).  It works fine at the top 25% and the bottom 40% approximately.

I have checked the connections and they all seem OK - any suggestions please to get it to work properly over the whole screen?

I first noticed it using PiCorePlayer but have also confirmed the symptoms using Raspbian latest version.  Presumably it is a hardware problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like the screen has probably died from some kind of physical fault. The only way I can think of to ensure it may not be is to try it with a different RPi, but that seems like a long shot.

I'd suggest that accepting that the parrot is no more.

Comment: I think you are probably right. I have ordered a new screen and will report back once tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem using this display on  ArchLinux-ARM.
I was working fine today till evening. 
After dinner I perform a system update and now the touchscreen doesn't work correctly. I got a dead zone (only for the touch functionality) in the top side of the screen. I definitely  cannot touch on the top side of the screen.
I got other issues also in libinput inside Xorg. I think that it could be an upgrade problem (pointing to Waylan or Weston or libinput) - I know that with evdev I got no problem at all before, but something changes after upgrade, and libinput is the future (evdev will be deprecated)...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same problem in about 10% the units I've seen. After more than a year the touch area gets a dead zone that eventually grows until it's all gone. We use the same software on all units, so, it's most likely some kind of electrical issue.